# Использование RSA-ключей из AndroidKeyStore для установки SSL-соединения

Tags: android, ssl, tls, keystore, pkcs#12

Я сохраняю клиентские `RSA-ключи` и `сертификат CA` в `AndroidKeyStore` для последующего извлечения и создания SSL-контекста. При попытке установления SSL-cоединения получаю `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed`.

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x72c004a240: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   2019-10-04 11:07:23.042 21015-21174/xxx.xxx.xxx W/System.err: error:10000418:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:579 0x72c00149c0:0x00000001)
>   2019-10-04 11:07:23.043 21015-21174/xxx.xxx.xxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>   2019-10-04 11:07:23.043 21015-21174/xxx.xxx.xxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374)
>   2019-10-04 11:07:23.043 21015-21174/xxx.xxx.xxx W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217)

Если я использую `PKCS12 KeyStore` вместо `AndroidKeyStore`, то SSL-соединение проходит успешно. Но в хранилище `PKCS12` я не могу сохранить ключи в отличие от `AndroidKeyStore`, мне приходится загружать их при каждом соединении. Я подозреваю, что проблема в том, что в `PKCS12` и `AndroidKeyStore` ключи и сертификаты хранятся в разных форматах. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Код получения `SSLContext`:

```
  KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    if (!keyStore.containsAlias("Client")) {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            ks.load(mCertPKCS12, password.toCharArray());

            keyStore.setEntry("Client", ks.getEntry("Client", null), null);
            keyStore.setEntry("Server", ks.getEntry("Server", null), null);
    }



   KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyClient = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry("Client", null);
    if (keyClient != null)
        Log.d("###", "keyClient=" + keyClient.toString());

    Certificate certClient = keyClient.getCertificate();
    if (certClient != null)
        Log.d("###", "certClient=" + certClient.toString());

    final Certificate certServer = keyStore.getCertificate("Server");
    if (certServer != null)
        Log.d("###", "certServer=" + certServer.toString());

    // Build a TrustManager, that trusts only the server certificate
    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            for (int j = 0; j < chain.length; j++) {
                chain[j].checkValidity();
                try {
                    chain[j].verify(certServer.getPublicKey());
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchProviderException | SignatureException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new CertificateException(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };


    String defaultAlg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    Log.d("aaa", "default cypher algorithm: " + defaultAlg);

    // Build a KeyManager for Client auth
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(defaultAlg);
    kmf.init(keyStore, null);

    SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
```